# Removing the blue border sorrounding the angular google map - agm-map

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-google-maps

how to remove this blue border around this `agm-map`
see the pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIiQd.jpg?

once i click on the map, the blue border disappears!

i've tried with:

```
agm-map {
    height: 465px;
    width: 600px;
    outline: none !important;
  }
```

or

```
  agm-map:focus {
    outline: none !important;
  }
```

but it doesn't work

**further information**: the `agm-map` is placed inside an `angular material modal`

Answer (score 0):

It's focus on them map for accessibility

This should do the trick to hide it.

```
::ng-deep .gm-style div {
  border: none !important;
}
```

There is also ticket for this here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182937497?pli=1

Answer (score -1):

You can remove blue border by just adding following style

```
  ::ng-deep.agm-style div {
border:0px !important
}
```